# Problems of defining a factorial function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm recently starting to learn coding in Python, this is the code that I tried to define a function that helps me to find the factorial of a number. Yet, this chunk of code always returns me the double of its factorial.

```
def factorial(x):
   empty = None
   try:
      adj_x = int(x)
   except:
      print("Invalid Input")
   if adj_x < 0:
      print("Invalid Input")
   elif adj_x == 0:
      print(0)
   else:
      l_adj_x = adj_x - 1 # if input == 4, this is 3
      r = range(1, l_adj_x) # 1, 2, 3
      for k in r:
         n = adj_x - k # 4-1 = 3, 4-2 = 2, 4-3 = 1
         if empty is None:
            empty = n
         else:
            empty = empty * n
         n_adj_x = adj_x * empty * n
      print(n_adj_x)
```

I realized that it is the problem of the `n` in this line:

```
n_adj_x = adj_x * empty * n
```

Based on my own understanding, the last `n` in the for-loop should be 1 (I took 4 as an example of my input and stated all the possible outcomes of the loop in the comments next to each line of code) , if so, why does it appear to be the double of the correct answer (when I include `n` in `n_adj_x = adj_x * empty * n`) since the `n` should equal to 1?

Comment: I think you make the logic overcomplex than necessary.  You could learn to debug your own code here - https://pythontutor.com/   first.

Comment: as an aside, `except: ... print("error")` is **not** what you want it to do... *just let the error propagate*. Printing "invalid* input and *continuing to run the function* is not correct

Comment: I can't understand how you intend for the logic to work. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to explain, step by step, exactly what you expect to happen for, say, `n = 5`.

Comment: I really don't understand what you were intending with `empty`

Comment: As an aside: the factorial of 0 should be 1, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to get is the factorial here are some
examples:

Example 1

```py
n = 10
factorial = 1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    factorial *= i
print(factorial)
```

---

Example 2     <-- worst option
Slowest option and requires the most additional memory.

```py
def fact(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return 1
    return x * fact(x - 1)
print(fact(10))
```

---

Example 3    <-- Best option

```py
import math
print(math.factorial(10))
```

This is the python libs built in function and probably performs better than my simple loop, however I have not tested it.

Comment: noooo not example 2!

Comment: Why is `best` or `worse`?  Good to elaborate it - for uninitiates.